# Why DetailsView.ChangeMode method does not fire ModeChanging and ModeChanged events?

Tags: asp.net, detailsview

I have an ASP.NET WebApplication page with DetailsView bounded to SqlDataSource.

When I try to change mode by auto-generated Edit or Insert buttons, events are fired.

When I try to change mode programmatically by DetailsView.ChangeMode method call (inside  custom button click), ModeChanging and ModeChanged events are not fired.

Why it does not work ?

There is aspx listing:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <h1><asp:Label ID="Label" runat="server" Text="ReadOnly" /></h1>
    <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource" 
        EnableModelValidation="True"
        AllowPaging="True" 
        AutoGenerateEditButton="True"
        AutoGenerateInsertButton="True" 
        OnModeChanged="DetailsView_ModeChanged">
        <FooterTemplate>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:DetailsView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PEMDConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [evd].[WaterTemplates]"
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [evd].[WaterTemplates] (TemplateName,TemplateDescription) VALUES (@Name,@Description)" />
    <asp:Button ID="InsertByChangeModeButton" runat="server" 
        OnClick="InsertByChangeModeButton_Click" 
        Text="Insert By ChangeMode" />
    <asp:Button ID="EditByChangeModeButton" runat="server" 
        OnClick="EditByChangeModeButton_Click" 
        Text="Edit By ChangeMode" />
</div>
</form>
```

and here is code behind:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreRender(e);
            switch (DetailsView.CurrentMode)
            {
                case DetailsViewMode.Edit:
                case DetailsViewMode.Insert:
                    EditByChangeModeButton.Visible = false;
                    InsertByChangeModeButton.Visible = false;
                    break;
                case DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly:
                    InsertByChangeModeButton.Visible = true;
                    EditByChangeModeButton.Visible = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        protected void InsertByChangeModeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DetailsView.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Insert);
        }

        protected void EditByChangeModeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DetailsView.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Edit);
        }

        protected void DetailsView_ModeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (DetailsView.CurrentMode)
            {
                case DetailsViewMode.Edit:
                    Label.Text = "Edit";
                    break;
                case DetailsViewMode.Insert:
                    Label.Text = "Insert";
                    break;
                case DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly:
                    Label.Text = "ReadOnly";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the complete code where you call changeMode() for detailsView

Comment: I attached the complete code, markup and code behind. Thank you. When I click on InsertByChangeModeButton or EditByChangeModeButton, the text of Label does not change.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: So far I have not found anything.